# PDO not insert some values but insert others

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is what I have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<?php 

include_once("../conexao.php");
include_once("../check_session.php");
include_once("../set.php");
$username = $_SESSION["username"];


 $profileimage =  $username.'.png';
 //echo $profileimage;

//assign post vars 

$post_name = $_POST['loginname'];
$post_surname = $_POST['loginsurname'];
$post_description = $_POST['profiledescription'];
$post_local = $_POST['local'];
$post_streetnumber = $_POST['streetnumber'];
$post_streetaddress = $_POST['streetaddress'];
$post_city = $_POST['city'];
$post_state = $_POST['state'];
$post_postalcode = $_POST['postalcode'];
$post_country = $_POST['country'];
$post_addressreference = $_POST['addressreference'];

//variavel $conexao_pdo

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :usr";

                    //db column and value
        $stmt1 = $conexao_pdo->prepare($sql1);  
        //where clause                                 
        $stmt1->bindParam(':usr', $username);
        $stmt1->execute();  
        while ($linha = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
  //echo $linha->name . ' - ' . $linha->email;
  $col_name = $linha->name;
  $col_surname = $linha->surname;
  //$col_email = $linha->email;
  $col_description = $linha->description;
  //$col_profileimage = $linha->profileimage;
  $col_local = $linha->local;
  $col_streetnumber = $linha->streetnumber;
  $col_streetaddress = $linha->streetaddress;
  $col_city = $linha->city;
  $col_state = $linha->state;
  $col_postalcode = $linha->postalcode;
  $col_country = $linha->country;
  $col_addressreference = $linha->addressreference;
}

$stringsize = strlen($post_description);

if(empty($post_name)){ $name = $col_name;  } else { $name = $post_name; }
if(empty($post_surname)){ $surname = $col_surname;  } else { $surname = $post_surname; }


if(!empty($post_description) && ($stringsize <= 150)){ $description = $post_description;  } else { $description = $col_description; }



if(empty($post_local)){ $local =  $col_local;  } else { $local = $post_local; }
if(empty($post_streetnumber)){ $streetnumber =  $col_streetnumber;  } else { $streetnumber = $post_streetnumber; }
if(empty($post_streetaddress)){ $streetaddress =  $col_streetaddress;  } else { $streetaddress = $post_streetaddress; }
if(empty($post_city)){ $city =  $col_city;  } else { $city = $post_city; }
if(empty($post_state)){ $state =  $col_state;  } else { $state = $post_state; }
if(empty($post_postalcode)){ $postalcode =  $col_postalcode;  } else { $postalcode = $post_postalcode; }
if(empty($post_country)){ $country =  $col_country;  } else { $country = $post_country; }
if(empty($post_addressreference)){ $addressreference =  $col_addressreference;  } else { $addressreference = $post_addressreference; }



$sql = "UPDATE user SET name = :name, 
            surname = :surname, 
            description = :description,  
            profileimage = :profileimage,  
            local = :local,
            streetnumber = :streetnumber,
            streetaddress = :streetaddress, 
            city = :city, 
            state = :state, 
            postalcode = :postalcode, 
            country = :country, 
            addressreference = :addressreference
            WHERE username = :username";

            //db column and value 
$stmt = $conexao_pdo->prepare($sql);  
//where clause                                 
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);  
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);    
$stmt->bindParam(':surname', $surname);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $description); 
$stmt->bindParam(':profileimage', $profileimage); 
$stmt->bindParam(':local', $local); 
$stmt->bindParam(':streetnumber', $streetnumber); 
$stmt->bindParam(':streetaddress', $streetaddress); 
$stmt->bindParam(':city', $city); 
$stmt->bindParam(':state', $state); 
$stmt->bindParam(':postalcode', $postalcode); 
$stmt->bindParam(':country', $country); 
$stmt->bindParam(':addressreference', $addressreference); 

$stmt->execute();
//sucess 
    echo "<span style='color: green;' class='fa fa-check fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></span> "; 


 ?>
```

This is what I am trying to do if input field is empty it will update with The current values that are in the db column, but it input it not empty it will update with the $_POST['vars'] assigned to the fields

I am sending two form at once via jQuery in the form page

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendforms">submit</button>
             <div id="result"> </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#sendforms").click(function() {
                       var combinedFormData = $("#form1,#form3").serialize();
                     $.post(
                            "ok.php",
                            combinedFormData
                     ).done(function(data) {
                            //alert("Successfully submitted!");
                            $("#result").html(data);
                     }).fail(function () {
                              //alert("Error submitting forms!");
                     })
              });
            });
        </script>
```

It's all working if I echo the `$_POST['vars']`;

The problem is that pdo is not updating the second form with id="form3" I don't know why I know it's not a post problem because I tested it, it's a PDO issue.

Apache last error log:

```
Access: `127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2017:16:48:48 -0300] "-" 408 - "-" "-"`
```

error

```
[Mon Apr 24 16:35:23.680683 2017] [:error] [pid 6096:tid 1764] [client 127.0.0.1:51396] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: addressreference
```

for some reason the post index name it's shown as a error

On post via jQuery I got a url like this : `index.php?loginname=&loginsurname=&profiledescription=` very weird because It's a post request not get also the jquery should be posting in the ok.php page but it shows this parameter in the url after post

Here is the image when I perform an ajax call

[image]

I think it's probably a problem with PDO query limit size is there a way where I can increase it ?

By my experience before I had a problem with pdo to insert in db a checkbox value it's not the case in this question but may help us to find what is wrong With PDO.

When I retrieve error info from PDO

```
echo $conexao_pdo->errorInfo();
```

It returns to me `Array`

using print_r

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

Using var_dump

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }
```

I check if it's executed with success and it's

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  $_SESSION['result'] = "ok";
} else {

    $_SESSION['result'] = "not ok";
}
```

It's getting ok result but yet not saving into db

Comment: So what error message are you getting?

Comment: No error messages

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: How do i check the error logs?

Comment: I have some deja vu here - seems we've discussed this before. The error logs are on your web server. They are text files you can read.

Comment: Show the HTML for the two forms.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, there's no `name="addressreference"` in the form.

Comment: Barmar It's not the html dude I tested it to see $_post vars, it's working and there is the name="addressreference" in the form input but it's a text area, pdo is crazy don't know why it's not saving it

Comment: The AJAX post goes to `ok.php`, not `index.php`. The URL you show is not from the AJAX request.

Comment: It's not a PDO error. The error message is from the line `$post_addressreference = $_POST['addressreference'];`

Comment: Index.php is where is the form page , ok.php it's the db insert page, I already change $post_addressreference but it still not saving into db

Comment: Open Developer Tools, go to the Network tab, and look at the request details for the AJAX call to `ok.php`.

Comment: As I told you the jquery send a post request to ok.php but the url shows liks this  index.php?loginname=&loginsurname=&profiledescription=

Comment: The URL in `$.post()` is `ok.php`.

Comment: Updated the question with the ajax result

Comment: I think it's probally a problem with PDO query limit size is there a way where I can increase it ?

Comment: By my experience before I had a problem with pdo to insert in db a checkbox value it's not the case in this question but may help us to find what is wrong With PDO

Comment: The default size of the mysql packet size is quite high, unless you posting an entire volume of encyclopedias you aren't likely hitting that limit.

Comment: But is very werid because the first form works well but the second form don't work

Comment: `$conexao_pdo->errorInfo();` what is the output of this after the `$stmt->execute()` statement?

Comment: It outputs      `Array`

Comment: `var_dump($conexao_pdo->errorInfo());` it's going to be very obvious what the error is after that.

Comment: `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }`  this is the result but I tested only with a value in the second form other values I let empty because to send you the comment answer faster

Comment: That says there is no problem, which means your update statement is working properly. What's the value of perhaps your inputs aren't what you think they are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142548/discussion-between-otavio-barreto-and-augwa).

Comment: I think it's a problem with if(empty($post_name)) because I removed thid and worked but I need it because if empty it will assign the $var to add in db to the current db value

Comment: See my question updates

Comment: Hi I would like to tell everyone that I solved the issue, see my answer to know what was happenning, Thanks to that, `I found a new bug in jquery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem, I had 3 forms with ids: `#form1, form2, #form3` but I was sending via jquery 2 forms only

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendforms">submit</button>
             <div id="result"> </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#sendforms").click(function() {
                       var combinedFormData = $("#form1,#form3").serialize();
                     $.post(
                            "ok.php",
                            combinedFormData
                     ).done(function(data) {
                            //alert("Successfully submitted!");
                            $("#result").html(data);
                     }).fail(function () {
                              //alert("Error submitting forms!");
                     })
              });
            });
        </script>
```

The order of the form in html is:

```
<form id="form1"><!--form content here --></form>
```

**Here was the error in the second form**

```
<form id="form2"><!--form content here -->
```

Form 3

```
<form id="form3"><!--form content here --></form>
```

> The second form there was not a  **close tag**  but is very weird
>   **jquery.serialize** Behave this way because the **#form2** has nothing to do
>   with the other forms and the jquery code, the jquery was send just the
>    **#form1** and **#form3** so the **#form2** has nothing to do with the forms was serialized and posted, I could not imagine this was the problem but
>   now I found this jquery bug and gained more experience.
>
> Thanks everyone for trying to help, if someone face the same problem please
>   refer to this question.